# Selecting Element attribute using Jquery

Tags: jquery

```
<ul class="top singleSelect" id="g-dropdown" data-type="singleSelect" role="listbox">
    <li id="li-0" data-level-id="10001" class="li-level1" tabindex="0">
        <ul id="ul-0">
           <li tabindex="-1" data-level-id="" id="li-0-0" class="li-level2">
```

I need to select the attribute data-level-id of inner li

Can someone help me to select the element using jquery?

Comment: $("#li-0-0").attr("data-level-id")

Comment: or `data('level-id')`

Comment: Have you made any kind of effort to do this yourself?

Comment: Can't use ID of li as it is creating dynamically multiple li's... ID's will keep on continue like li-0-0 li-0-1 li-02. I want select that attribute of all the li's

Comment: Yeah i was trying.. can't select direct data(level-id) also... as it is there with parent and child li's

Comment: @user2349508 What can you select? You need to tell us what is the starting place

Comment: You must clarify the question. Then the answers will appear.

Answer (score 2):

```js
//select all children li that have a data-level-id attribute on them
var elements = $('#g-dropdown').find('li[data-level-id]').filter(function() {
  //exclude elements that have a nested li with a level id
  return $(this).find('li[data-level-id]').length < 1;
});

console.log(elements.get());
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="top singleSelect" id="g-dropdown" data-type="singleSelect" role="listbox">
  <li id="li-0" data-level-id="10001" class="li-level1" tabindex="0">
    <ul id="ul-0">
      <li tabindex="-1" data-level-id="" id="li-0-0" class="li-level2">
        Find Me
      </li>
    </ul>
  </li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Please, for the love of jQuery, make it $('#g-dropdown').find('li[data-level-id]')

Comment: You could do that, sure.  But the scope of the selector is pretty small so the performance different would be negligible

Comment: How can i store the value of this function into a variable ?

Comment: Are you wanting the variable to contain the elements, or the value of the data fields?

Comment: i want to store the element into variable .. select the element with data field and store into a variable

Comment: @Taplar It's not if there's ton of other li[data-level-id] on the page (which we don't know if there is, there isn't or there will be). It has to check ancestry for all of them. (I upvoted, though ;) )

Comment: @talpar, yeah that attribute is there for parent li also and child li also right. i want to select child li data attribute only and strore that respective element into variable

Comment: @talpar, your answer will select all both child and ancestor lis under main ul. i want to select only child li with attribute

Comment: @talpar... This is inner li  <li tabindex="-1" data-level-id="" id="li-0-0" class="li-level2">.. i want to select inner li only with data-level-id attribute. Parent li( <li id="li-0" data-level-id="10001" class="li-level1" tabindex="0">) should not be selected where it also has the same attribute

Comment: @user2349508 ok, so now it should only find lis that do not belong to other lis that also have that attribute on them.

Comment: @talpar yes... i tried your latest answer. But its returning undefined :(

Comment: Updated with a snipplet to see if it is returning what you want. @user2349508